# JavaFX GridPane adding elements dynamically

Tags: java, javafx

JavaFX newbie here, I'm trying to create a GridPane dynamically, so far I'm able to create it specifying the following:

```
GridPane gridPaneMain = new GridPane();

           gridPaneMain.add(button1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
           gridPaneMain.add(button2, 1, 0, 1, 1);
           gridPaneMain.add(button3, 2, 0, 1, 1);
           gridPaneMain.add(button4, 3, 0, 1, 1);
           gridPaneMain.add(button5, 4, 0, 1, 1);
           gridPaneMain.add(button6, 5, 0, 1, 1);
           gridPaneMain.add(button7, 6, 0, 1, 1);
           Scene scene = new Scene(gridPaneMain, 800, 800);

           ImageView imv1 = new ImageView();
           ImageView imv2 = new ImageView();
           ImageView imv3 = new ImageView();
           ImageView imv4 = new ImageView();
           ImageView imv5 = new ImageView();
           ImageView imv6 = new ImageView();
           ImageView imv7 = new ImageView();

           Image image1 = new Image(BoardGameMain.class.getResourceAsStream("viewcontrollers/blank.png"));
           imv1.setImage(image1);
           imv2.setImage(image1);
           imv3.setImage(image1);
           imv4.setImage(image1);
           imv5.setImage(image1);
           imv6.setImage(image1);
           imv7.setImage(image1);

           final HBox pictureRegion1 = new HBox();
           final HBox pictureRegion2 = new HBox();
           final HBox pictureRegion3 = new HBox();
           final HBox pictureRegion4 = new HBox();
           final HBox pictureRegion5 = new HBox();
           final HBox pictureRegion6 = new HBox();
           final HBox pictureRegion7 = new HBox();

           pictureRegion1.getChildren().add(imv1);
           pictureRegion2.getChildren().add(imv2);
           pictureRegion3.getChildren().add(imv3);
           pictureRegion4.getChildren().add(imv4);
           pictureRegion5.getChildren().add(imv5);
           pictureRegion6.getChildren().add(imv6);
           pictureRegion7.getChildren().add(imv7);

           gridPaneMain.add(pictureRegion1, 0, 1);
           gridPaneMain.add(pictureRegion2, 1, 1);
           gridPaneMain.add(pictureRegion3, 2, 1);
           gridPaneMain.add(pictureRegion4, 3, 1);
           gridPaneMain.add(pictureRegion5, 4, 1);
           gridPaneMain.add(pictureRegion6, 5, 1);
           gridPaneMain.add(pictureRegion7, 6, 1);
```

Any suggestions how to create it dynamically without specifying each element?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a for loop?

```
GridPane gridPaneMain = new GridPane();
Image image = new Image(
            BoardGameMain.class.getResourceAsStream("viewcontrollers/blank.png"));
for (int x = 0; x <= 6; ++x) {
    Button button = ...;
    gridPaneMain.add(button, x, 0, 1, 1);
    ImageView imv = new ImageView();
    imv.setImage(image);
    final HBox pictureRegion = new HBox();
    pictureRegion.getChildren().add(imv);
    gridPaneMain.add(pictureRegion, x, 1);
}
Scene scene = new Scene(gridPaneMain, 800, 800);
```

Comment: Urgh... Loading the same image once per `ImageView` although you know it's the same used with all of them...

Comment: I literally just copy-pasted the given code and removed the redundant elements, as to make it seem most familiar to the user.  I agree it can be improved upon, but the important thing here was to get across how to "add elements dynamically".